# Computing Euler angles from rotation matrix: boundary cases

Tags: matlab, rotation, rotational-matrices, euler-angles

I want to compute the **Euler angles** from a rotation matrix in order to find out the orientation associated to that rotation. For that purpose, I am using MATLAB and the function **rotm2eul** that gives me the rotation first about x-axis, then about y-axis and finally the z-axis.

I am using a signal with 1000 frames and for each frame a rotation matrix is computed, as well, the three Euler angles. However, when I am going to see the Euler angles' curve, there is some "**jumps**" as I shown on the figures below.

[image]

[image]

On Technique 1, I think it jumps from -180º to 180º which should be the same. In fact, the upper portion of the plot seems a continuation of the lower portion. So in this case I thought I could **subtract 360º** to the upper portion to get the plot. But I am not sure if I do this I am **falsifying the results**.

On Technique 2, it makes a jump with a different reason of the previous one. I think it must be because the angle associated with the y-axis **reaches 90º** which should be a boundary case. But in this case I don't know how should I correct the data or , like previously, if I want to correct the plot is falsifying the euler angle result.

Comment: In Euclidean geometry, the angles are unique only up to a factor of 360° (2\pi). In the top case, you can use the function [`unwrap`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html) to automatically adjust the angles to minimize the jump by adding or subtracting 2\pi. However, without seeing your code, some example data, and your expected output for techniques 1 and 2, it is impossible to tell you whether either is "correct".

Comment: You might consider using quaternions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technique 2: This is a [Gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock#Loss_of_a_degree_of_freedom_with_Euler_angles), known feature of Euler angles. You can't avoid it completely. You can change the rotation order, but it will appear in another position.